# Are there any synonyms for the noun 'crush'?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I must clarify, when I say 'crush', I mean the subject of an unrealistic, one-sided infatuation. For example, it can be used in this sentence: 'My celebrity crush is David Beckham.'

Could that word be interchanged for another? Preferably, can it be a word which is not necessarily too formal/complex? I've searched online for a while but can't find any synonyms for this form of 'crush.'

I want the word for a novel which is set in an old-ish fantasy period so I don't think 'crush' would feel in-place.  The main character is a lower-class worker.

Comment: Why do you need a different word (especially if you want it to be "not too formal/complex").  Luckily there is a word for what you are describing.  It's ***crush***.

Comment: I am writing a novel which is set in an old-ish fantasy period so I don't think 'crush' would feel in-place. Also, the main character is a lower-class worker so it wouldn't make sense for her to know too many formal words.

Comment: That is important information and should be included in the question.

Comment: Although the first citation (1891) in the full OED is over a decade later than ***crush***, I think the noun usage ***pash*** has more of a "Victorian" flavour today.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm a bit new to this site so I didn't expect much justification to be required.

Comment: @MatthewBain- Welcome.  It's not so much justification as it is clarification that helps us to identify a suitable word.  Without that info, *crush* would seem appropriate.  This information rules that out and helps point us in a better direction. With that in mind, would you say your "old-ish" fantasy time period aligns more closely with early 1900's, 1800's, 1700's?

Comment: You're writing a novel without a thesaurus? Like giving a speech without a teleprompter. Scuba diving without a watch. Skydiving without a ... well whatever.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I think that *pash* is excellent, and that you should repost that as an actual answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try ***yearning***  It would fit in a fantasy story in a long-ago setting.

> Gwyneth had a powerful yearning for Sir Mortimer, a yearning she knew
>   she must keep to herself.  (made up)

Yearning, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yearning)

> A persistent, often melancholy desire; a longing

Example, from [Henry David Thoreau](http://thoreau.thefreelibrary.com/Walking/1-1#yearning).

> I do not know of any poetry to quote which adequately expresses this
>   yearning for the Wild

To substantiate that it is an old word with an old flavor, see [Etomonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=y&p=1&allowed_in_frame=0)

> yearning.yearning (n.) Old English gierning, verbal noun from yearn
>   (v.).
>
> yearn (v.) English giernan (West Saxon), geornan (Mercian), giorna
>   (Northumbrian) "to strive, be eager, desire, seek for, beg, demand,"
>   from Proto-Germanic *gernjan (source also of Gothic gairnjan "to
>   desire," German begehren "to desire;" Old High German gern, Old Norse
>   gjarn "desirous," Old English georn "eager, desirous," German gern
>   "gladly, willingly"), from PIE root *gher- "to like, want"

Comment: I love this. Perhaps a quick explanation of gerunds? +1 anyway

Comment: Having old roots doesn't give a word an old flavor.  Consider words like *yellow*, *comb*, *boat*, and *ice*; just as old of a pedigree, yet not archaic in the least.

Answer (score 3):

While not a noun, you could use the verb *[moon](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/moon)*

> Act in a dreamily infatuated manner:
>   *Timothy’s mooning over her like a schoolboy*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

It is often used as a phrasal verb with *over* and an object, although it can be used without, as in *Stop mooning!*

Comment: many fantasy novels have slightly different words anyway, to add flavor, so you could use moon as a noun and let the unfolding of the story (and perhaps someone asking "is she still mooning over him?") make it make sense.

Comment: Of course, if Timothy is mooning her then that means something else entirely.  (And I haven't heard "moon" used to mean infatuation in 20-30 years.)

Comment: @HotLicks Inspired by his request for an old-timey term.

Answer (score 3):

**Besotted** would fit the context

> besotted
>
> completely in love with someone and always thinking of them : He was
> so completely besotted with her that he couldn't see how badly she
> treated him

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/besotted

Given the setting, the language and grammar are usually very differently formed from modern English, hence:

> 'I am truly besotted with Sir Beckham of Stow-on-the-Wold.'

Answer (score 2):

Wandering around a thesaurus, the best I found was a synonym for beloved, lover, or passion:  [flame](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flame?s=t):

> 8. Informal. an object of one's passionate love; sweetheart:
>      He's taking out his new flame tonight.

The problem that I'm seeing is that most of the words for a target of infatuation are lacking the unrequited aspect of crush.  You wouldn't take out a crush.  If you are, they've stopped being a crush and moved on to being something more realistic.

Perhaps consider using the adjective [unrequited](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unrequited?s=t) in addition to or in place of whatever noun.  E.g. **unrequited flame** or simply **unrequited**.  Perhaps we have more time for foolish romance than our ancestors did and developed a single word (crush) for something that they would have expressed more complexly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [puppy love](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puppy-love) or [calf love](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/calf-love) can apply.

puppy love, calf love

> Intense but relatively shallow romantic attachment, associated with adolescents.
>   *Then he reels off the imponderables - physical development, puppy love, adolescent angst - that can ruin even the most promising tennis career.*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/puppy-love
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/calf-love

Answer (score 1):

[source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adulate?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic).]

Adulate
verb (used with object), adulated, adulating.
1.
to show excessive admiration or devotion to; flatter or admire servilely.